# Switching alt key for command key - logitech k750 on (os x 10.11.3)

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm just trying to set mac layout on my logitech k750 keyboard so alt works as command key and (windows) command key works as alt key.

I tried to use "Preferences > Keyboard > Modifier keys > Unifying Device" where I switched option key for command key, but that doesn't have any effect.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Karabiner-Elements for this. It works well too. Download it [here](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/).

Comment: `[here]` is not a valid link ;). Also please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. Provide more than just a link, for example some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: "[here] is not a valid link ;). :"

Yes, I know, I saw it as soon as I posted but couldn't see where to edit. No matter, the answer is all the original poster needed in this case. Sometimes more words than necessary do not add clarity. Thanks for the heads-up anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about the 750 keyboard but on my 850 press and hold FN-O for three seconds to switch to mac mode.  That swaps the Alt and command keys amongst other things.

Comment: I had to disable "Always keep keyboard in Windows layout" in the 'Logitech Options" software (for windows), but then this worked for me on a K780. Thanks!

Comment: I use logitech k375 and to change cmd and alt, pressing FN+P for three seconds. It runs proper for Windows 10 and MacOS Catalina. I suprised why this information doesn't exist logitech sofware or user manual.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Holding `Fn + O` and `Fn + P` indeed seems to toggle the alt and command keys.